# changing function based on window size

Tags: javascript, css, function, mobile

I have the following function controlling the height and margin of my site elements

js

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.height = "70vh";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginTop = "70vh";
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}
```

I want to the `style.height` line and `style.marginTop` to change to `20vh` on screen and `70vh` on mobile

Tried applying  `if ($(window).width() > 768)` with no success

EDIT: based on the responses I realize I am missing important information. The function is called by an onclick event, (something different when not clicked, or clicked a second time) which is why the styling is in the javascript.

Comment: even with the new information - this should be done with CSS - what you can do in the javascript - is to add / remove classes to the page structure to give the different styling. This means you are using to hte javascript to add the class and the css for that class still lives in the css. It is better to not mix the js and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you could do this with javascript (check out matchmedia) - it is a simple media query to set the height based on the viewport width

The following sets the vertical height based on the viewport width (based on Bootstrap 3's breakpoints) - you may want to change the breakpoints - but its best to use CSS instead of javascript to set style rule declaration.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #mySidenav {height: 20vh}
  #main {margin-top: 20vh}
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #mySidenav {height: 70vh}
  #main {margin-top: 70vh}
}
```

If you Really, absolutely, desparately want to use javascript then window.matchmedia is your friend (but may not be fully cross browser compliant)

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
  /* The viewport is equal to or less than 767 pixels wide */
      #mySidenav {height: 20vh};
      #main {margin-top: 20vh}
} else {
  /* The viewport is more than 767 pixels wide */
      #mySidenav {height: 70vh};
      #main {margin-top: 70vh}
}
```

**But i stongly advise using CSS for this.**

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated my question as I realize as it was worded, simple css would have worked.

Comment: @user3550879 - even with the new information - this should be done with CSS - what you can do in the javascript - is to add / remove classes to the page structure to give the different styling. This means you are using to hte javascript to add the class and the css for that class still lives in the css. It is better to not mix the js and css

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for something like this. Here is a working example:

```css
#main,
#mySidenav {
  height: 20vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #main,
  #mySidenav {
    height: 70vh;
  }
}


/*** JUST FOR DEMO ***/

#main,
#mySidenav {
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>

<div id="mySidenav"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated my question as I realize as it was worded, simple css would have worked.